# Mogoid 7.0.4 returns Unable to autoload constant (Mongoid ~6 worked fine)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

When I try to upgrade to Mongoid ~7, it throws this error:

```
            Unable to autoload constant User::AuditSession, expected ./testapp/app/models/user/audit_session.rb to define it
```

I indeed have this file, but it defines AuditSession, not User::AuditSession. I put all the user related models into this directory which worked in Mongoid ~6, but it seems to no longer work in Mongoid ~7.

Is there any workaround I can do to get the old behaviour? - My goal is to avoid moving all my model files or editing all my class names.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Rails conventions, if the model is defined in `user/audit_session.rb`, the class name should be `User::AuditSession`.

A workaround is to preload the class so that it is loaded by the time it is needed. Depending on where the class is used from, this could be as simple as placing

```
require 'user/audit_session'
```

in the file that uses AuditSession.

Alternatively you could define a top-level `audit_session.rb` which includes the other file (i.e. just has the above include in it).

Comment: Yes, I understand this is what it is expecting. My question is how can I force the old behaviour that Mongoid ~6 had of not requiring User::AuditSession and just using AuditSession.

Comment: I don't know the details of your application and why its behavior changed, other than as far as I know Rails has had the behavior I described for a long time. I imagine creating a small reproduce case of the "old behavior" ( i.e. an application with a single model in the "wrong" location) would help to shed light on why it was the way it was.